# Copy main menu from one window to other

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to set a new parent window (host window) for the another window (client window) that belongs to other process. Also, the is a requirement to duplicate main menu of the client window so that the host window should have the same working main menu as the calient window has.
I managed to set the client window menu to the host window, but the host menu does not work. It is possible to navigate through menu, but  is does not work (f.e. it not possible to open/create new file).

The question is if it possible to do this at all and if it is, what did I miss?

There is a code snippet:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetMenu(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetMenu(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hMenu);

    private Process notepadProcess;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStart();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        EmbedNotepadWindow();
    }

    private void ProcessStart()
    {
        notepadProcess = new Process();
        notepadProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        notepadProcess.Start();
    }

    private void EmbedNotepadWindow()
    {
        SetParent(notepadProcess.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
        var menuHandle = GetMenu(notepadProcess.MainWindowHandle);
        SetMenu(this.Handle, menuHandle);
    }
}
```

[Copy main menu from Client to Host window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HJMC.png)

Comment: None of this is realistic. You can't expect to have cross process parent relationships as has been discussed here, and elsewhere, many times.

Comment: What makes you assume that Notepad would respond to a menu in your process, a process that Notepad doesn't even know exists? And with that being the far easier problem to solve, make sure to read [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) to learn about the tough one.

Comment: You could remove the `WS_SYSMENU`, `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_THICKFRAME` styles, so it looks like the Menu is part of your app :) If you size the Window as the container.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and the provided links, probably, there is other approach to achieve the goal.